# Calling Oracle Stored procedure from VBA ADODB

Tags: vba, oracle, stored-procedures, ms-word, adodb

Hi
I am trying to use a stored procedure in WORD VBA to retrieve some addresses using a stored procedure to populate a list field.

```
Private Sub txtCpny_AfterUpdate()  
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset  
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim param1 As ADODB.Parameter  
Dim param2 As ADODB.Parameter  
Dim strCpny As String  

strCpny = GetSearchString(Me.txtCpny) 'ie %Name%  

Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")  

With cmd  
  .ActiveConnection = mcn  
  .CommandText = "LISTPARTNER_NAME"  
  .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc  
  Set param1 = .CreateParameter("RCT1", adInteger, adParamInputOutput, , Null)  
  Set param2 = .CreateParameter("firmaName", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, strCpny)  
  .Parameters.Append param1    
  .Parameters.Append param2    
  Set rst = .Execute  
End With  

...Using the recordset here  

rst.Close  
Set param1 = Nothing  
Set param2 = Nothing  
Set cmd = Nothing  
End Sub
```

The Stored Procedure looks as follows: The SQL should result in a recordset holding the matching Companies.

```
PROCEDURE LISTPARTNER_NAME (  
firmaName    IN   VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,  
RCT1         IN OUT GLOBALPKG.RCT1
)  

AS  
BEGIN  
  OPEN RCT1 FOR  
  SELECT  
  ...  
  FROM  
  ...  
  WHERE  
  KNAG.NAME_ORG LIKE LISTPARTNER_NAME.firmaName  
  ...  
END LISTPARTNER_NAME
```

When the command is executed VB throws a RunTime Error

```
ORA-06550: Line 1, column 13:  
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to  
'LISTPARTNER_NAME'  
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:  
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

In my opinion the I am doing something wrong wit the parameters. Ihave been trying various versions of setting the parameters with no luck
Any Clues?
Thanks

Comment: have a look at this thread, it may be of assistance (well messed up posting link so I put it in an answer below)

Answer (score 1):

have a look at this thread, it may be of assistance
http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=360922

The only other thing I could suggest would be switching the order of the parameters (so they are in the same order -- I know ODP defaults to order but I am unsure of ADODB)

Answer (score 1):

I have been successfully using this code in Access:

```
Function runAdo(sql As String, usr As String, pwd As String)
'by Patrick Honorez - www.idevlop.com  ----- 09-nov-2012
'Purpose   :  run Oracle proc using ADO connection

    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    cn.Open GetPersonalizedConnectStringADO(usr, pwd)
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.Open sql, cn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
    cn.Close
End Function
```

I rarely use ADO from Access, since I find DAO simpler to use, but in this case I had to execute some Oracle procs requiring a different UID, and creating a new DAO Querydef specifying different UID and PWD, did not work, perhaps due to the fact that Access keeps a cache of connections.
So I decided to use ADO for the second "user" and it works like a charm.